# Best Way to Update/Insert and Reorganize List

Tags: java, data-structures

**Overview**: So currently I have a `Map<List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>` for a game where the key and value system looks like this:

```
mapid: List<characterid, donation_amount>
```

To explain, each map has an id and a player can donate X amount of in game money to that map to become the donation king of the map. This map logs their ID and how much they've donated in total the past month.

**Issue**: Currently, I'm deciding the best way to implement a descending ordered list that contains the highest donor for each map. This is what I had in mind.

```
Map Id       Character Id       Amount
100000            3             100000
110000            4             200000
100000            5              10000
110000            6             100000
200000            7                  0
```

I store my data in a SQL table when the game saves or closes, which is then retrieved by the following function.

```
public void loadDonations() {
    try (PreparedStatement ps = DatabaseConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM medal_rankings ORDER BY donated DESC");
         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

        while (rs.next()) {
            int mapid       = rs.getInt("mapid");
            int characterid = rs.getInt("characterid");
            int donated     = rs.getInt("donated");

            if (!donations.containsKey(mapid))
                donations.put(mapid, new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>());
            donations.get(mapid).add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(characterid, donated));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LogHelper.INVOCABLE.get().info("DonorKing: failed to load donations"); 
    }
}
```

When a player makes a donation, the whole data structure is updated and reorganized in this manner.

```
public void addDonation(int amount, int mapid, int characterid) {
    List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> map_donations = donations.get(mapid);
    if (!donations.containsKey(mapid))
        donations.put(mapid, new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>());
    if (!map_donations.contains(characterid))
        map_donations.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(characterid, amount));
    else {
        for (int x = 0; x < map_donations.size(); x++) {
            List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> donation = map_donations;
            if (donation.get(x).left == characterid) {
                amount += donation.get(x).right;
                donation.remove(donation.get(x));
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < map_donations.size(); x++)
            if (map_donations.get(x).right <= amount) {
                map_donations.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(characterid, amount));
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

**Afterthoughts**: What I don't like is that the worst time complexity of this can be O(N^2). Justification for this is that I may iterate to the end of the list to find my element, remove it, and then iterate over the list again until I find an area to insert it at.

Is there a better way to improve my existing code, or even better, adopt a new system at approaching this particular issue?

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't be able to utilize a TreeMap<Integer, Double> with a reverse comparator. What's the point of a List as the key of the Map?

Comment: The map id is the key. The value is a list

Comment: @Jacob G. Responded

Comment: Oh I see, a good data structure to use for this would be a TreeMultimap from Guava's collections API.  It'll allow you to sort the collection of values, which can be a new object that holds the character's ID and the amount they donated, with a custom comparator.